# UnsatisfiedLinkError when consuming prebuilt shared library in Android project with Cmake

Tags: android, c++, cmake

I am building an android library that uses some functions that are implemented in native code. I have successfully included the .so files in my library and the `System.loadLibrary()` works fine. The issue is whenever I try to call any method or even use a public property from the loaded native library I am getting an UnsatisfiedLinkError crash. The important project details are,
CmakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
        native-lib

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        IMPORTED

#        SwigWbc_wrap.cpp
#        src/main/java/com/onespan/digipass/sdk/wbc/jni/SwigWbc_wrap.cpp
)
set_target_properties(
        # Specifies the target library.
        native-lib
        # Specifies the parameter you want to define.
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION

        # Provides the path to the library you want to import.
        src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libnative-lib.so
)
include_directories(src/main/jniLibs)
```

The stacktrace

```
Process: com.example.library.sdk.sample, PID: 5337
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.example.library.SwigWbcJNI.WBC_PLAINTEXT_INCORRECT_LENGTH_get() (tried Java_com_onespan_digipass_sdk_wbc_jni_SwigWbcJNI_WBC_1PLAINTEXT_1INCORRECT_1LENGTH_1get and Java_com_onespan_digipass_sdk_wbc_jni_SwigWbcJNI_WBC_1PLAINTEXT_1INCORRECT_1LENGTH_1get__)
    at com.example.library.SwigWbcJNI.WBC_PLAINTEXT_INCORRECT_LENGTH_get(Native Method)
    at com.example.library.SwigWbcConstants.<clinit>(SwigWbcConstants.java:12)
    at com.example.library.sdk.WBCSDKImpl.init$lib_debug(WBCSDKImpl.kt:24)
    at com.example.library.sdk.WBCSDK$Companion.createWBCSDKInstance(WBCSDK.kt:22)
    at com.example.library.sdk.sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:22)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8341)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8320)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1417)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3622)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3778)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:138)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7884)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

I have generated JNI wrappers using Swig and the shared folders are the correct spot, I also have one header file which I have included in the cmake file. I am at my wits end with this.

The definition in the header file used for generating the binding looks like this

```
#define WBC_PLAINTEXT_INCORRECT_LENGTH -40`
```

The generated native function is

```
SWIGEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_onespan_digipass_sdk_wbc_jni_SwigWbcJNI_WBC_1PLAINTEXT_1INCORRECT_1LENGTH_1get(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls)
```

The java function is(I get a `Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function` here btw but the app runs still)

```
public final static native int WBC_PLAINTEXT_INCORRECT_LENGTH_get();
```

Comment: Please show the definition of the native function on the Java and C++ side.  It looks at though the generated names do not match.

Comment: Also if you're using C++, make sure the JNI function is extern C to avoid name mangling

Comment: @RichardCritten I have added the functions, please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: Since the JNI function is Swig generated I am unsure if this is the issue, there is a 
```#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif``` at the top of the class afterall

Comment: Use the `nm` tool that comes with the NDK to verify the symbols in your library, and that you matched the ABI to the one on your device/emulator

Comment: Running `nm -D` shows a list of symbols including the native methods I am trying to consume